# Some fascinating CometD communication behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, cometd

I have a Java- based CometD client that uses a publish to get some data. The application gets the information without problems, but then a series of strange things happen:

1. The connection with the client times out. This is a regular thing that I have been unable to prevent.
2. The client re- establishes a connection with the server. It seems to do this by starting up another thread which actually repeats the request for the same information!
3. The client gets the same information over again. Depending on what it does, client application behavior gets screwed up.
4. The connection times out again, then the cycle repeats. This happens for as long as the client is running.

   As a result, I am seeing client behavior deteriorate over time. Dialog boxes get duplicated, more and more threads are created and I am seeing multiple timeouts, multiple requests for the same information, and more wasting of the application's resources processing the same information over and over again.

   I need to find a way to stop this. Can someone tell me the following:
5. Is there a way to control timeouts. I have tried various ways based on the CometD documentation to at least lengthen the time to timeout. None of them seem to work. I would prefer to turn off timeouts completely if that is possible.
6. How do I prevent the client from continually resending the same data request? My clients are not guaranteed to always have connections (some of them will be phones or tablets running in remote areas where the signal will be less than reliable). Is there some way to stop clients from resending already completed requests when their connections are restored?

   Someone please advise...

Comment: You are better off joining the CometD mailing list to provide full details of your issue. Typical reason for your first bullet is that your application blocks inside a CometD listener, and this is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_concepts_threading). The rest is probably just a consequence of that.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I *hate* mailing lists because they tend to fill up my inbox long after my questions are answered -- assuming they even are answered. That is why I bring my questions to venues like this one. Still, if that is my best chance, I;ll see you on the mailing list...

Comment: Well, yours is not a _question_, it's a request for troubleshooting a problem that you have on an environment comprised of a client and a server with their respective configurations, so perhaps SO is not the right place to use when you look for troubleshooting help, which may involve several exchanges of information to figure out the problem. If you hate mailing lists, then use [CometD's issue tracking](https://bugs.cometd.org) and file an issue with all the relevant details. Try to make the problem reproducible for the CometD developers.